# Am I getting a race condition with my boost asio async_read?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, race-condition

```
bool Connection::Receive(){
    std::vector<uint8_t> buf(1000);
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_,boost::asio::buffer(buf,1000),
            boost::bind(&Connection::handler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    int rcvlen=buf.size();
    ByteBuffer b((std::shared_ptr<uint8_t>)buf.data(),rcvlen);
    if(rcvlen <= 0){
        buf.clear();
        return false;
    }
    OnReceived(b);
    buf.clear();
    return true;
}
```

The method works fine but only when I make a breakpoint inside it. Is there an issue with timing as it waits to receive? Without the breakpoint, nothing is received.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Try using ',' or '.' for example...

Comment: Please don't use slang.  "so weird" is not a question, and "w8ting" is not a real word.  This isn't a forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to read from the receive buffer immediately after starting the asynchronous operation, without waiting for it to complete, that is why it works when you set a breakpoint.

The code after your async_read belongs into `Connection::handler`, since that is the callback you told `async_read` to invoke after receiving some data.

What you usually want is a `start_read` and a `handle_read_some` function:

```
void connection::start_read()
{
    socket_->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(read_buffer_),
        boost::bind(&connection::handle_read_some, shared_from_this(),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void connection::handle_read_some(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        // Use the data here!

        start_read();
    }
}
```

Note the shared_from_this, it's important if you want the lifetime of your connection to be automatically taken care of by the number of outstanding I/O requests. Make sure to derive your class from `boost::enable_shared_from_this<connection>` and to only create it with `make_shared<connection>`.

To enforce this, your constructor should be private and you can add a friend declaration (C++0x version; if your compiler does not support this, you will have to insert the correct number of arguments yourself):

```
template<typename T, typename... Arg> friend boost::shared_ptr<T> boost::make_shared(const Arg&...);
```

Also make sure your receive buffer is still alive by the time the callback is invoked, preferably by using a statically sized buffer member variable of your connection class.

Comment: @xDD it gives me this Error `tr1::bad_weak_ptr`

Comment: Make sure you are not using `shared_from_this()` inside the constructor, as not everything is set up at that time. You might want to create a public static helper function that creates a connection using `make_shared` and then calls `start_read()`.

Comment: @xDD look i have three classes check them u will understand what am trying to do

Connection
http://pastebin.com/zWQHVgSp

ConnectionFactory
http://pastebin.com/fyx4eZdZ

Server
http://pastebin.com/3DAcH7Db

i dont know how to make it work as you telling me :/

Comment: Try something like this: http://pastie.org/1996902

And you should also consider templating your server on the connection type rather than passing around factories (that's very Java-style).

Comment: @xDD i did use the codes u pointed me to but still the same error `tr1::bad_weak_ptr`

Comment: Oh, you are mixing up std::shared_ptr with boost::shared_ptr, use the one from boost if you want shared_from_this functionality.

Comment: @xDD yeah it was coz i mixed the both but now `void Connection::start_read(){
 socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(read_buffer_),
 boost::bind(&Connection::handle_read_some,shared_from_this(),boost::asio::placeholders::error,boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
void Connection::handle_read_some(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  if(!error)
  {
   ByteBuffer b((std::shared_ptr<uint8_t>)read_buffer_.data(), bytes_transferred);
   this->OnReceived(b);
   start_read();
  }
  else{
   this->Disconnect();
  }
}
` nt invokin the handle read

Comment: Make sure you are running the io_service on at least one thread and that you are actually receiving data. If you can't seem to find the cause it would probably be best to open a new question.

Comment: @xDD i made a new question thnx for your time :)